OpenVPN Access Server Stuck on License Agreement
I followed the steps from the OpenVPN Access Server Portal to install OpenVPN Access Server on an Ubuntu Server 22 headless VM. After installing and automatically configuring the service, I went to log in at the admin portal and once I did I was presented with the license agreement, only when I click Agree it just refreshes the page and does nothing. So I went back and manually reconfigured the service with the /usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init tool and I was presented with the exact same issue. I looked through the logs and I couldn't find anything obvious there either, but I'll post them here if anyone thinks it will help.
Am I doing something wrong here or is my installation just broken? 

Just a guess, but did you scroll all the way to the bottom?

@OrganicMarble Yes I did

The same problem occurred with openvpn-as installed on RHEL8. I think this is an openvpn-as issue, not an Ubuntu issue.

Delete all iptables rules (MUST)
Install openvpn-as
Breaking the agreement (openvpn-as actually automatically customizes iptables here. If rules are already set, the setup script here will not work properly)

wish you good luck.
